# Running the Chrome Browser headless using selenium webdriver with Cucumber on Ubuntu

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chrome, linux

I have a setup that runs on mac fine (currently launches browser and uses chromium), what i need to do now though is get this running on `Ubuntu 14.04` (Amazon EC2 instance), and have chrome or chromium running heedlessly. I have tried quite a few things now and when running a cucumber test i get the following error every time

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 3.13.0-116-generic x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

This is my current setup

```
# Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake'
gem 'cucumber', "~> 2.4.0"
gem 'capybara'
gem 'rspec-expectations'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', "~> 3.0.0"
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'retriable', '~>1.4'

# env.rb

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
 chrome_binary = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

 capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_binary, "args" => ['headless', 'disable-gpu'] })
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
end
```

I have also installed chrome driver and xvfb

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb

wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
chmod +x chromedriver

sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

though when running `which chromedriver` it outputs

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hendricks-as3-integration/bin/chromedriver
```

so i uninstalled the `chromedriver-helper` gem and when running `/usr/bin/chromedriver` i get

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Is there a way to specify what chromedriver to use?

Has anybody got experience with setting this up or perhaps can spot something that i have not done?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: Chrome Driver and Chrome are separate, you'll need to ensure you also have Chrome installed on the remote machine or use Selenium Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the internets sake. You need to add `no-sandbox` to your args.

```
"args" => ['headless', 'disable-gpu', 'no-sandbox']
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961